# For any positive positive integer prove that $3n(3n+1)^2<4((3n)!)^{1/n}$

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** For any positive positive integer prove that $3n(3n+1)^2<4((3n)!)^{1/n}$.

WE have $\frac{1+2+\dots+3n}{3n}>((3n)!)^{1/3n}\implies \frac{3n(3n+1)}{2\times 3n}>((3n)!)^{1/3n}\implies (3n+1)^3>8((3)!)^{1/n}$.

How can I show the required result?

Added: If $3n(3n+1)^2>4((3n)!)^{1/n}$, then is it possible to prove this?

Comment: Your addition doesn't make too much sense: you ask whether or not we can deduce an inequality of the form $A>B$ if we are allowed to assume $A<B$ and indeed, as an answer showed, your inequality doesn't hold for $n=3$. In the interests of salvage attempts, applying Stirling's Formula gives $n^3<(3/e)^3 n^3 < ((3n)!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ which maybe is of interest.

Comment: If instead you are actually interested in proving $3n(3n+1)^2> 4((3n)!)^{1/n}$ and not the inequality in the title, then you are almost done: your working implies $1/2\cdot (3n+1)^3 > 4((3n)!)^{1/n}$ and since $(3n+1)/2 < 3n$ for $n\geq 1$ you're done.

Comment: What is a "positive positive integer"?

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$, $(\dfrac{n+1}{2})^n > n!$

You can see this intuitively as $\dfrac{n+1}{2}$ is the average of the numbers $1,2,...,n-1,n$.

\begin{equation}
(\dfrac{3n+1}{2})^{3n} > 3n!
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(3n+1)^{3} > 8\cdot (3n!)^\dfrac{1}{n}
\end{equation}